# Modifying a list and passing it to another command

Tags: math-mode, programming, etoolbox, comma-separated-list

I am trying to write some macros to easy my life while writing mathematics in LaTeX. For this, I would like to have some macros to write wedge products in a more concise manner.
I have a command which typesets general wedge products based on a comma separated list:

```
\DeclareListParser*{\forcommalist}{,}
\NewDocumentCommand{\wedgeproduct}{s m}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{\forcommalist{\listadd\wedgelist}{#2}}{\forlistloop{\listadd\wedgelist}{#2}}
    \newcounter{wedgelength}
    \forlistloop{\ifnumequal{\value{wedgelength}}{0}{}{\wedge}\stepcounter{wedgelength}}{\wedgelist}
}
```

(using xparse and etoolbox). I am trying to define a macro `\diffform` as follows

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\diffform}{m}{%
    \forcommalist{\listadd\formlist{}d}{#1}
    \wedgeproduct*{{\formlist}}
}
```

But when using it as (in mathmode)

```
\diffform{x,y}
```

It gives the following error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...}{\wedge }\stepcounter {wedgelength}{\formlist 
                                                  }
l.21    \diffform{x,y}
```

I do not really understand what is going wrong (because it should not be looking for `\formlist` but for `\wedgelist`).
How can I solve this problem? Any references to general explanations about programming macros like this in (Lua)TeX are also appreciated.

Full source code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclareListParser*{\forcommalist}{,}
\NewDocumentCommand{\wedgeproduct}{s m}{%
        \IfValueTF{#1}{\forcommalist{\listadd\wedgelist}{#2}}{\forlistloop{\listadd\wedgelist}{#2}}
        \newcounter{wedgelength}
        \forlistloop{\ifnumequal{\value{wedgelength}}{0}{}{\wedge}\stepcounter{wedgelength}}{\wedgelist}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\diffform}{m}{%
        \forcommalist{\listadd\formlist{}d}{#1}
        \wedgeproduct*{{\formlist}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
        \diffform{x,y}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than `etoolbox`, I'd go with the more powerful and less clumsy `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\diffform}{m}
 {
  \hoekstra_diffform:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__hoekstra_diffform_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__hoekstra_diffform_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hoekstra_diffform:n
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__hoekstra_diffform_in_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__hoekstra_diffform_out_seq \l__hoekstra_diffform_in_seq { \diff ##1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__hoekstra_diffform_out_seq { \wedge }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\diffform{x} \qquad \diffform{x,y,z,t}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The working is as follows:

1. The input is split at commas and populates a sequence.
2. A new sequence is built from it by adding the “differential d” in front of each item.
3. The new sequence is delivered, with `\wedge` in between items.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm.

Comment: +1: But I fear that this will soon cause your reputation to exceed the Porsche number :) (911k).